# What is the difference between a Solution and a Project in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Could anybody kindly advise me what is the difference between Solution and project in vb.net
If I load either of this from my project folder, will effect be the same?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The concepts are visual studio concepts and are not specific to VB.NET.

A solution can contain several different projects.

If you load a solution that contains several projects, they will all load and you will be able to compile them as one unit. You cannot do this if you open a single project.

See this article - [Structuring Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) for in-depth guidance on how to use solutions and projects.

Answer (score 13):

A solution is a container for projects. A single solution may contain zero or more projects. Loading the solution file will load all the associated projects. If you are using project references between the projects in the solution (one project depends on another) opening only the project file might not compile as it won't be able to compile the referenced project.